# Bobril framework with different router

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, bobril

I try to use [bobril](https://github.com/Bobris/Bobril/blob/master/examples/router/app.ts) with no hash router, with fully history, for example /about, not #/about. Bobril do not know it, but should be possible use different route, for example from Reactjs or the others. 
For compilation I'm using [Bobril build](https://github.com/Bobris/bobril-build).

Can you help me, how to do it? Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will need some nontrivial amount of changes in bobril-build to add feature that it will respond with index.html instead of 404 and also all generated links inside index.html will have to be absolute. I don't have time to add this feature myself atleast next 2 weeks.
Than any history based router independent of view library will work. Actual code to route to specific "page" could look like this:

```
b.init(() => <AboutPage />);
```

or without TSX:

```
b.init(() => AboutPage());
```